# debugging with eclipse

Tags: eclipse

[image: Rosanswers logo]

hi, i struggle a lot with using ros with eclipse

first of all, i did all that is standing on the ros with IDE page. i can import the project to eclipse and build it. the indexer is absolutely not working (it recognizes rosnode etc, but i get errors like "namespace std is amgiguous" - i use eclipse kepler). however, for now i just ignored that, because i can still do some autocompletion stuff etc.. building works fine, but when it comes to debug the program, i have no clue what to do. the tutorial says:

"Create a new launch configuration, by clicking on Run --> Run configurations... --> C/C++ Application (double click or click on New). Select the correct binary on the main tab (Search project should work when your binary was already built). Then in the environment tab, add (at least)" --> which binary? i cannot execute the binary directly, right? i have to use rosrun. so what should be in there? i dont see any binaries listed when i click on "search project"

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/128186/debugging-with-eclipse/) by [shangl](https://answers.ros.org/users/11871/shangl/) on ROS Answers with karma: 11 on 2014-02-11

Post score: 0

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Not a whole answer, but there is no problem executing binaries directly. rosrun only exists to make finding them easier.

Sadly, I don't have any input on why Eclipse isn't finding your executables in the first place. In general, CMake and catkin place executables in devel/lib/{package_name}/{binary} when they're built.

---

Originally posted by [ahendrix](https://answers.ros.org/users/1034/ahendrix/) with karma: 47576 on 2014-02-11

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 0

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [shangl](https://answers.ros.org/users/11871/shangl/) on 2014-02-12**:
do i have to pass some special arguments to it? when i call a binary working perfectly fine with rosrun, it crashes with a segmentation fault

**Comment by [ahendrix](https://answers.ros.org/users/1034/ahendrix/) on 2014-02-12**:
You shouldn't have to pass any special arguments, but you may need to set the LD_LIBRARY_PATH environment variable if eclipse/ROS integration doesn't do that for you. Beyond that, I'd run it in a debugger.